# VB6 OpenRecordSet has too few parameters?

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm debugging an app with the following code:

```
sql = myTable
Set datTable.Recordset = myDB.openRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

where

```
sql = "select * from table Order by Precipition,Date/Time"
```

An error occurs on the second line saying "Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 2". I believe the issue is the with the value of sql.  I don't know to much about SQL, so does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thingk you can try

```
sql = "select * from table Order by Precipition,[Date/Time]"
```

Note the "[]"

You should try to avoid using table names/columns that contains spaces, or keywords, as this will make life very dufficult.

Use name that explain the field in context to the table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your order clause: more specifically here:

Date/Time.